# Set default values based on selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am trying to do is when the user selects a city, by default the miles is entered and the zip code is just left alone, blank.

The following is code I allows a user to select a city based on a list that will display. I also provided the zipcode and the miles and how they are generated as well.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="city" 
          ng-model="searchParam.City" 
          ng-options="City.value for City in Cities">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-7 no-padding-right">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="distance" 
        ng-model="searchParam.Distance" 
        ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"></select>
        <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-5 no-padding-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" 
             id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" 
             placeholder="Zip code" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to do the following with what I am understanding:

```
<script>
   function citySelected(){
      if(searchParam.City.selected){
          not sure how to set miles to default 
          not sure how to say leave zip code blank
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: you are new to javascript and you are using angular js !

Comment: By the look of the code you are using AngularJS which you did not disclose. It is important to tag your questions properly and let people know any external libraries you use so someone may help you.

Comment: @AL-zami Like I said, I am trying to write it in Javascript. The previous person who wrote this is in angular js, you are correct

Comment: @Jim yes you are correct. I will edit the tags right away

Comment: is this what you are trying to do: https://plnkr.co/edit/vAbP4Sz6saxRBSib9wsU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You know that you are using angularjs?

For your model you need a controller like this

```
module.exports = function($scope) {
    var default = '50';
    $scope.Distance = default;
    $scope.Zip = '';
};
```

Can't see your angularJS implementation. You did copy+paste?

Comment: Is their a way to determine whether the city was selected and do what you just did

Comment: With AngularJS* you have many possibilities to handle your model (- the dynamic data you are using on your webpage). I actually don't know what's your background knowledge > so just to get into JS, I would personally try to use pure JS only and I would not use the angular html attributes. If you've been into Angular, try to get deeper into it. Anyways, I would run some tutorials or examples in the Angular Docs, to get into the basics of JS or Angular (e.g. at the w3schools website). *) Angular is just one frontend framework, there are others for sure,which might provide a similar functionality

Comment: in other words: your question and the example you provided is imo a little confusing. its clear what you want (handle specific data dynamically at frontend) - but its unclear how you want to achieve it (using Angular or pure JS). thus your example has to be modified very broadly (in an so far uncertain direction). so my suggestion would be.. run a few tutorials that deal with your topic and than specify your question. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I've got of your question: is that you want to change the miles accordingly to city selected, is it?

I'm not sure if my interpretation was correct, but I made this snippet:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.cities = [  
         {  
            "name":"Alabama",
            "distance":"400"
         },
         {  
            "name":"Arkansas",
            "distance":"600"
         },
         {  
            "name":"New York",
            "distance":"800"
         }
      ];
    })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="city" ng-options="city as city.name for city in cities">
      <option value="">--Select city--</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 no-padding-right">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="distance" ng-model="city.distance">
          <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 no-padding-left">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="zip" placeholder="Zip code">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```